# Why is global variable executed twice in React

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I'm a newbie on frontend development and learning React. Now I'm trying to build a hello-world project.

After executing `npx create-react-app myapp`, I got an initial React project and I just coded in the file `App.js`.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

var counter = 0;

function App() {
  const [counter2, setCount] = useState(0);
  const increment = () => {
    setCount(counter2 + 1);
  };
  
  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick= {increment}>Increment</button>
      <h1>{counter++}</h1> // 1, 3, 5, 7... WHY???
      <h1>{counter2}</h1>  // 0, 1, 2, 3...
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

After executing `npm start`, I got my index page, which contains three parts: a button and two numbers.

To my surprise, when I click the button, `counter2` is increased as expected, but `counter` is increased twice. Meaning that keeping clicking the button gives me the result as below:

`1 0`, `3 1`, `5 2`...

Why is the global variable `counter` increased two by two, instead of one by one?

Furthermore, what is the difference between React State and common global variable?

Comment: Yes, I have noticed this in my React app - it executes twice. Even if you put `console.log()`, it does twice. Memoisation maybe?

Comment: _Furthermore, what is the difference between React State and common global variable?_ Global variable change will not trigger React Re-Rendering of component.

Comment: How are you rendering your App? Is it wrapped in React.StrictMode?

Comment: @NickParsons Well, I think it is the method by default of React: `ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you wrap a component in `<React.StrictMode>`, it will run certain functions twice, one of these being the function body of your functional component:

> This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> ... Function component bodies
>
> - [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)

This is only done in dev mode, and the idea behind doing it is to help you catch side-effects within your project.

It may seem as though your component is only being executed once though, as putting a `console.log()` inside of your functional component will only run once per state change. This is because, as of React 17, they have updated the console.log method to *not* log on the second invocation of your function:

> Starting with React 17, React automatically modifies the console
> methods like console.log() to silence the logs in the second call to
> lifecycle functions
>
> - [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)

However, there is a workaround to this by saving a reference to the `console.log` method, and using that to perform your logs. Doing this will allow you to see that your component is being executed twice:

```
const log = console.log;
function App() {
  const [counter2, setCount] = useState(0);
  const increment = () => {
    setCount(counter2 + 1);
  };
  log("Rendering, counter is:", counter);
  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick= {increment}>Increment</button>
      <h1>{counter++}</h1> 
      <h1>{counter2}</h1> 
    </div>
  );
}
```

The above will output the following when the component mounts, showing that the function body is running twice:

```
Rendering, counter is: 0
Rendering, counter is: 1
```

If you remove the `<React.StrictMode>` component then counter will increase by one each render, as React will no longer double-invoke your functional component body, and your component body will only be called once:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

In terms of global variables vs state, the main difference has been pointed out in a [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65472211/why-is-global-variable-executed-twice-in-react/65472357#comment115752399_65472211). That is that when you update your state with `setMethodName()`, you'll cause your component body to rerender, which doesn't happen when you update a normal variable as React won't be aware of the changes made to it.