# Strange behavior when generating an id for a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to generate a unique id number for each React component, this id will be assigned to the component when it is mounted.

I am using the code below, the function *callOnce* takes a function and ensure that the function is only executed once per component.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
// Helper function that makes fn execute only once
const callOnce = (fn) => {
  let called = false;
  let result;
  return (...params) => {
    if (called) return result;
    called = true;
    result = fn(...params);
    return result;
  };
};

let lastId = 0;
const getId = () => {
  console.log("incrementing");
  lastId = lastId + 1;
  return lastId;
};

export default function App() {
  const { current: getIdOnce } = useRef(callOnce(getId));
  const id = getIdOnce();
  return <div>{id}</div>;
}
```

When I execute this code, the id that is displayed is 2, but logically it should be 1.
The getId function is only called once (the message *incrementing* is printed once), so there is no other way that the variable lastId is incremented again.

Why is the value 2 ?

[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-nobel-bb3tr)

Comment: Why? As in: why are you doing this, React is already highly optimized, what are you trying to do that makes you think assigning ids will let you do that?

Comment: Eventually each component will send REST requests, i need a way to track the loading state of each component ( using redux ), i am trying to avoid using useState to limit the times the components are rendered

Comment: That's what reducers are for? Each component has its own reducer, and doesn't need to know anything other than its own state and actions. Also, the whole point of React is that a component's state is the data underpinning your UI, so if your component's state is updated, it _should_ render. Any value that can change but _not_ lead to a UI update is not state, and should not be put in there. (remember, React lives inside of the larger world of "it's all just JS", if you need to track non-state data, it's a normal class or function that has all the functionality of normal JS available)

Comment: So basically i am creating a framework on top of redux to handle async data (like apollo). To do this, I don't want each component to have its own reducers, instead i want each store to have its own reducers, so that many components can call the same action = same reducer to update fetched data. which means i need to track loading for each component somewhere else, to do that  I need to uniquely identifiy a component.  I know i am going outside of the scope of a normal React app, but i think it is necessary

Comment: Sounds like you're fighting the river instead of following its flow. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in another thread. Basically when using React with React.StrictMode wrapper, some functions are executed twice.
The reason the id is 2 is because the function getId is executed twice

[Link of the answer with more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65472211/why-is-global-variable-executed-twice-in-react)

Answer (score 1):

I not know what the problem, but the fix can be that:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
// Helper function that makes fn execute only once
const callOnce = (fn) => {
  let called = false;
  let result;
  return (...params) => {
    if (called) return result;
    called = true;
    result = fn(...params);
    return result;
  };
};

let lastId = 0;
const getId = () => lastId++;

export default function App() {
  const { current: getIdOnce } = useRef(callOnce(getId));
  const id = getIdOnce();
  return <div>{id}</div>;
}
```

If I found the problem reason, I will update my comment ☺